# How to compute -1 / (-343)^(1/3) as 1/7 in Python?

Tags: python, math, exponentiation

I like to incorporate Python in my exploration of functions, however I have encountered a behavior that I didn't expect or want for these assessments.

```
>>> def h(x):
...     return -1 / x**(1/3)
...
>>> h(-343)
(-0.07142857142857145 + 0.12371791482634838j)
```

I would like a true inverse to the following function:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**3
...
>>> f(-7)
-343
```

Such that:

```
>>> def h(x):
...     return -1/inverse_f(x)
...
>>> h(-343)
0.14285714285714285
```

Is there a Pythonic way to get this behavior?

Comment: Python programmers do not normally use `lambda` when a function will be called by name. You want to define named functions, such as `def h(x): return -1 / x**(1/3)`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have changed the definitions accordingly.

Comment: Well, now you have incorrect indentation. I would actually say it was fine before, as long as you _know_ that `lambda` is not ordinarily used in this way.

Comment: @DavidZ The OPs indentation is fine.

Comment: I appreciate the comments on style all the same. I am aware of PEP8, and pylint to improve my code style as I develop.

Comment: In fact, your functions are correct, but a cubic root of a negative number has three values; you are getting one of them, but apparently want another one. Is that correct?

Comment: @DYZ (3 comments up) And using named lambda functions in an example is also fine. Neither of these things are best practices, sure, and that's something to be aware of, but neither one is a problem when asking a question.

Comment: @Galen the built-in `x**(1/3)` returns the so-called principal branch of the cube root function. The principal branch is the one with the smallest argument (i.e. angle away from the positive x axis). There are two other branches; you want the one which falls on the negative x axis. Whenever you work with nth roots, you'll have to address this issue about principal versus some other branch. Try a web search for "nth roots of unity" for an introduction to this interesting and important topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting problems because a negative number raised to a fractional power can be a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

---

The solution is to apply a math identity. We know that if *x* is negative, then *x*<sup>1/3</sup> is equal to −((−*x*)<sup>1/3</sup>). In other words, we turn *x* into a positive number, take the cube root, and negate it again. Here is the Python code to do so:

```
def h(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return -1.0 / x**(1.0/3.0)
    else:  # x < 0
        return -h(-x)
```

---

To explain why you are getting the problem in the first place, it helps to look at the implementation of `x**y` (the power operator). The key mathematical identity is that *x*<sup>*y*</sup> = exp(log(*x*) · *y*). This identity makes it easier to handle powers, because the exponent is treated as a regular number and doesn't need to be analyzed (is it an integer? is it a fraction? is it negative? etc.).

When *x* is a positive number, log(*x*) is a real number. As long as *y* is also a real number, exp(log(*x*) · *y*) will be a real number.

But when *x* is a negative number, log(*x*) is a complex number. Specifically, it is equal to [log(-*x*) + π · *i*]. When we multiply such a complex number by *y* and then apply exp(), the result will usually be a complex number - which is not what you hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work in the **integers** only (and ignore the complex solutions of your function) this may be a way. at least for your example in the title it does what you want. (so this only addresses the title of your question; as the rest has changed now it will not help with that... [Nayuki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458631/4954037) will)

[`gmpy2`](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html#mpz-functions) has an `iroot` method:

```
import gmpy2
print(gmpy2.iroot(343, 3))  # -> (mpz(7), True)
```

starting from there you should be able to combine your function.

```
import gmpy2
from fractions import Fraction

def h(x):
    sign = 1 if x >= 0 else -1
    root, is_int = gmpy2.iroot(abs(x), 3)
    if not is_int:
        return None  # the result is not an integer
    root = int(root)
    return -sign * Fraction(1, root)

print(h(-343))  # -> 1/7
```

and the inverse:

```
def g(x):
    return -Fraction(1, x**3)

print(g(h(-343)))  # -> -343
```

Comment: @DYZ: exactly, that is what the `sign` and the `abs` are for! (oh, your comment was probably before i added the full function...)

Comment: A negative number has three cubic roots. Your code computes only one of them.

Comment: @DYZ: the program calculates the only integer one (or returns `None` if that does not exist). it looked to me that was what the OP was looking for. the complex ones are not mentioned anywhere. oops, right, now they appear in the question... will adapt my answer a bit.